# how to recover damaged memory card with the help of Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, memory-card

I have 16 gb micro memory card but it suddenly damage and unable to read and open. it only display in Disks utility.
also when I insert that memory card into mobile it display message **Damage memory card format it**. but if I format memory card I loss all my data. How can solve that issue. Here is screenshot of Disks Utility.

[image]

Comment: What filesystem was it?

Comment: fat file system

Comment: It seems your drive is toast. Can you make an image of it using the *Disks* application?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a Microsoft file system, **FAT32** or **NTFS**, try to repair the file system in Windows with

```
chkdsk /f X:
```

where X: is the 'drive' letter, for example D: or use a graphical tool in Windows. (You already know that you should *not* format it.)

If there is a linux file system, try to repair the file system in linux. Ubuntu uses the **ext4** file system, which can be repaired with

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, so for example `/dev/sdb1`

---

If no luck try **Testdisk**.

If still no luck try **PhotoRec**, which can recover files without a file system. The drive must be seen as a mass storage device, and Disks sees it as `/dev/sdb`, which indicates, that this is the case.

You find more details at these links,

[www.cgsecurity.org](http://www.cgsecurity.org)

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)

Answer (score -2):

Use testdisk it is a cli based recovery tool, scan your /dev/sdb/ storage, testdisk can recover lost files.

open terminal and apt-get install testdisk
and  use sudo testdisk and click enter on create here you can view all partition choose /dev/sdb/ and start recovery.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)