# SD card reader no longer detected in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, asus, sd-card, card-reader

I tried to mount an SD card into the reader.. with no luck. The OS does not detect the SD card reader at all.

the pc is an asus vivobook e200h.

I've tried a few common commands:

```
lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3496 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There are 2 usb's there, the wifi and the bluetooth one. No SD card reader here.

```
sudo lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 22)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 22)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)

dmesg | grep sd

[    2.594296] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.594302] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.598889] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:00: No vmmc regulator found
[    2.598897] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:00: No vqmmc regulator found
[    2.604482] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:03: No vmmc regulator found
[    2.604490] sdhci-acpi 80860F14:03: No vqmmc regulator found
[    5.132821]  i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm wmi video i2c_hid hid fjes sdhci_acpi sdhci
```

I don't know if these will help. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Check if there's a SD card driver,.

Comment: Please try 1) after rebooting. 2) in another card reader, 3) in another computer, 4) in another operating system
- If you still cannot 'see' the SD card as a drive, I think your SD card is 
damaged beyond repair (at least with tools for us regular users). 

If you can 'see' the  SD card as a drive, maybe the following link will help,

https://askubuntu.com/questions/874222/how-to-recover-damaged-memory-card-with-the-help-of-ubuntu/874352#874352

Comment: @sudodus don't forget 1.1) in same card reader in different USB port, assuming such are available.  (if it's plugged into a front port, try it in a back port, or vice versa.)

Comment: @sudodus 
1) i tried rebooting with the card inserted; poweroff inserted the card and turn on the pc and both doesn't work
2) i don't have a usb card reader to test if it work with this netbook, and in case it doesn't resolve my problem. 
3) the card is totally new and it work in another pc.

Comment: So something is wrong in 'this computer'. Ubuntu Gnome in this computer does not see it, but it works in another computer. 1) Which operating system is running in the computer, that can see the card? 2) Please run the following commands when the card in inserted and post the output (edit the original question to add the output), `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -ls`

Comment: all other pc and operating system can view the sd card and acces to it. the asus e200h have an integrated card reader but ubuntu don't recognize it. and obviously the sd card inserted in it.

Comment: @sudodus with these command i see only the internal partition of the pc.

Comment: It seems that your version of Ubuntu Gnome would need another hardware driver in order to see the card reader and the card. I don't know how to find such a driver. I can only  suggest that you try another version of Ubuntu Gnome (newer or older), or even another linux distro. You need not install anything, *try live* (booted from a USB drive), http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: @sudodus how can i find the driver and install it?

Comment: I don't know how to find it specifically. That's why I can only suggest that you try another version of Ubuntu Gnome (newer or older), or even another linux distro. You need not install anything, try live (booted from a USB drive). -- *Let us hope that someone else knows*, and can help you in a more specific way.

Comment: @sudodus i tried more distros of ubuntu and it doesn't work. debian is totally incompatible with these pc.

Comment: not sure if this is about the same hardware ([DebianOnAsusE200HA](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/E200HA)) -- indicates problematic kernel drivers ("4.7.1 & 4.7.2 sometimes work but sometimes freeze ... 4.8 & 4.9 don't detect").  upshot: try 4.7.x kernels or cross fingers for working drivers in a future kernel.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use a separate card reader, that you connect via USB?

Comment: @sudodus no, because i would like to use the sd to "expand" the memory of my pc (only 32gb)

Comment: @quixotic yes it's that pc

Comment: @quixotic found that there are severe driver problems with that MicroSD card reader. Would it be an option to use a [very small] USB pendrive to "expand" the memory of your pc? I understand that it would occupy one of the two USB ports, but when you need more USB connections, you can use a USB hub.

Comment: on the bright side, if you've ever wanted to get into kernel driver development, this looks like an ideal opportunity.  http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/

Comment: @quixotic ok, but.. how can i make a kernel module if the pc don't recognize nothing about the card reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ubuntu 18.04 the sd reader work fine.