# Dual Booting and "locking" hard drives (GParted repair fails and windows chdsk hangs on startup!)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have two Ubuntu (18.04 and 20.04) and one windows8 in my pc, so I have run my windows after around one year of not using that, and one of my hard drive has been locked, and I can not write files on it, so I can not repair the disk by GParted in my Ubuntu by the below procedure:

[image]

So I have tried the `chkdsk` command in my windows, and it was not successful, so I let windows restart itself and try disk repair on its startup page, and now it hangs on 35% of disk repair similar to below photo by difference of the Windows version and the repair percentage ([search link](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20hang%20during%20disk%20repair%20startup&sxsrf=AOaemvLwr9bllSSF9gVir3ialuAQhdQEPw:1631723978645&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw4_jAtYHzAhWEF3IKHSTMAnQQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA#imgrc=UA6CtYeGjKrYlM)):

[image]

If possible, I like to have some comment or answer for solving this problem in my  pc.

**Update 1:**

I have this pc almost form 2016, and I guess the hard drive is not too old, also the more information about the hard drive and its content files, could be seen below:

[image]

```
so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda  
[sudo] password for so: 

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD                  
    Serial Number:      S379J9EH703494      
    Firmware Revision:  2BE10001
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   0
    heads       15  0
    sectors/track   63  0
    --
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 5400
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = ?
    Advanced power management level: 254
    Recommended acoustic management value: 254, current value: 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
            Automatic Acoustic Management feature set
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
       *    Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Read/Write Long (AC1), obsolete
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    352min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 352min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50004cf2126633e7
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 0004cf
    Unique ID   : 2126633e7
Checksum: correct
```

**Update 2:**

I have tried the commnets written by `Curtis Gedak` and get belwo reprot:
[image]

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
[sudo] password for so: 
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-74-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M9T
Device Model:     ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD
Serial Number:    S379J9EH703494
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 2126633e7
Firmware Version: 2BE10001
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 22 09:05:07 2021 +0330
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (22020) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 367) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   092   083   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       2574
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4099
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       13352
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4155
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   062   023   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 12/77)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1732
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       285
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       37098
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   091   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       12729601
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   089   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       15326794

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5780         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed [00% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Also by seeing [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874222/how-to-recover-damaged-memory-card-with-the-help-of-ubuntu) post and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874222/how-to-recover-damaged-memory-card-with-the-help-of-ubuntu) i tried disk utility app of ubuntu and get below report:

```
file system ntfs on ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD is damaged
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: How old is the hard drive? Messing with commands from both OS that access the hard disk can make a mess.

Comment: Thanks, @David, I have updated the question and as I guess it doesn't give any notification, I have read this comment.

Comment: You might try running the GNU/Linux graphical program `gsmartcontrol`, or the command line program `sudo smartctl -a /dev/your-disk-device`, and then checking for any errors reported for the disk device.

Comment: Thanks, @Curtis_Gedak, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the below google tag:

[file system ntfs on hard is damaged ubuntu](https://www.google.com/search?q=file%20system%20ntfs%20on%20hatd%20is%20damaged%20ubuntu&bih=863&biw=1685&hl=fa&sxsrf=AOaemvLQL1lDti_GsL7li4zpJPlZXpiuzQ%3A1632289568359&ei=IMNKYe2mFamclwTNiJroAg&oq=file%20system%20ntfs%20on%20hatd%20is%20damaged%20ubuntu&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAwyBAghEAo6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABQxbARWPWzEWCguBFoCHACeAGAAesDiAGpC5IBBzItMS4yLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjttpG_8JHzAhUpzoUKHU2EBi0Q4dUDCA4)

and by help of this post:

[How do I fix NTFS from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901305/how-do-i-fix-ntfs-from-ubuntu)

I tried the `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5` command and as you can see below it is fixed :

```
so@so-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5

Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda5 was processed successfully.
```

Thanks.